# Fake click event - jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have this function

```
daysClick: function(e) {

    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.days');

    if (!$(parent).hasClass('disabled') && !$(parent).hasClass('readonly')) {
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('selected');
    }
}
```

How can I test this using jasmine?

I'm not sure how to fake click event basically.

Comment: extract logic into testable function, and put jQuery/DOM wiring to other one, that will be using your tested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [**uitest.js**](https://github.com/opitzconsulting/uitest.js).

It allows you to incorporate event handling and other UI features into your automated Jasmine tests.

```
var uit = uitest.current;

describe('someSuite', function() {
    uit.url('someUrl');

    it('should do smth when clicked on the button', function() {
        uit.runs(function($) {
            $(".btn").click();
        });
    });
});
```